# Transparent or transluscent header in Tizen native form

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to add transparent or translucent Header in Tizen native Form. In UI Builder it is possible to make translucent header in properties menu of a form. For implementation by programming I searched in `Form Header Style`. But couldn't find any hint for coding. I expect your helpful answers.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling `SetBackGroundColor` on your `Form`, with a `Color` that has alpha = 0x80 ?

Comment: @Michael please add your comment as an answer.